# UILabel with clickable links to functions

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm trying to create a news feed like: "user(clickable) ran for 3 minutes around Central Park(clickable)". The clickable links should just call a function where I can push a new ViewController.

UILabel doesn't support clickable links and I was wondering how I implement it. FancyLabel looks like it's very old (2008), TTTLabel seems like it handles only outside links, phones and addresses.

Comment: Try a uiwebview where the clickable parts are hyperlinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just use a UIWebView with a link and handle the pressing of the link in

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution at all. This is like suggesting someone use a Boeing 747 to carry apples when all they really needed was a handbasket. WebViews are *very* expensive memory and CPU wise

Comment: That's true. WebView's can be very expensive. But maybe those apples are VIP apples, and maybe OP needed those apples yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tap gesture recognizer to a UILabel thusly:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myMethodName)];
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

But depending on your requirements, I would probably recommend that you use a UIButton instead. We're used to clicking on links in the web, but in native apps it's usually more user-friendly to make tappable areas somewhat large (Apple recommends at least 44px).

Comment: I don't the user to click on the whole UILabel, only parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a uiwebview with delegate method.

Link the uiwebview and uiviewcontroller (delegate) in your storyboard.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Make sur, your url have "http://"

Answer (score 0):

[Fancy UILabels](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/) could be a solution for you.